Format every column from a SAS data set in a iterative way
I am new to SAS and came into a seemingly easy problem.
Suppose I want to convert every column to to a specific format/length based on its data type. The pseudo code will look like the following:
for col in df.columns:
    if col has dtype = 'Char', print col, and format it as $255.
    if col has dtype = 'Number', print col, and format it as best8.

I already have the SAS data output so the above loop probably needs to be in the data step, but can this be done earlier at the "import" / proc sql step as well?

How are you importing the data? That is the best place to create these settings and if the informat is incorrect, it won't matter what you set the format to anyways.

Hi @Reeza, I am importing it from Snowflake, and it is not easy to do the proposed loop there, but I agree with you I should look for resolving this at the source. So I am thinking of using a language I'm familiar with (e.g., Python) to generate the SQL query needed to process the data on Snowflake. (Python environment is not connected with SAS, but both are connected to Snowflake). Issue is default SAS data length from Snowflake VARCHAR is way too large, so I'm trying to change the informat here to fix the length (type is right), but due to large amount of attributes I want to use iteration.

Loops are not required in SAS. If you're truncating the options then use the option suggested by data null or dynamically generating your DBSASTYPE statement. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n0v4ma1zb9lu99n1728j279rjcqi.htm

Does this need to be done each column one by one, which means you need to type out the column names instead of using a position iterator? There are simply too many attributes..

Attaching a display format to a variable will not change how it is defined.

Are you use the SNOW libref engine to connect to Snowflake from SAS?

@szheng can u plz add an example of the data you have and the expected result

No loops required.  You could do with PROC DATATSET MODIFY and not create a new data set.
data class;
   set sashelp.class;
   format _character_ $255. _numeric_ BEST8.;
   run;
proc contents varnum;
   run;


Sounds like you want to measure the character variables and resize to min length.

%let data=sashelp.heart;
data clength(keep=_name_ _l_);
   set &data end=eof;
   array _1 _character_;
   array _2[20] 8 _temporary_;
   do over _1;
      _2[_i_] = max(_2[_i_],length(_1));
      end;
   if eof then do over _1;
      _name_ = vname(_1);
      _l_    = _2[_i_];
      output;
      end;
   run;
proc sql noprint;
   select catx(' ',_name_,cats('$',_l_)) into :clength separated by ' ' 
      from clength;
   quit;

%put NOTE: &=clength;

You can use &CLENGTH to redefine the character variable length.
68         %put NOTE: &=clength;
NOTE: CLENGTH=Status $5 DeathCause $25 Sex $6 Chol_Status $10 BP_Status $7 Weight_Status $11 Smoking_Status $17


Thanks! I was able to use this to change the data length for all columns. A follow up questions on the OP: if with more requirements, e.g., I want to set the data length (informat) for each column based on its max data length.
Say, if col has dtype = 'Char', and max char length is w, then set it to $w.

@szheng sounds like you want to resize the character variables?  I added to my answer.

An INFORMAT only comes into play when converting text into values.   So there is no need to change an INFORMAT attached to a variable when the variable already has data in it.  In a data step (or PROC DATASETS modify group) you can use informat _character_; to REMOVE any informats that are attached to the character variables.


Issue is default SAS data length from Snowflake VARCHAR is way too large, so I'm trying to change the informat here to fix the length (type is right)

Informats (or formats) don't set the length of the variable. Also I strongly recommend that you set the length as you download the data, not in a subsequent step, as very long fields are very slow to process.
Something like:
   data DL;
     length VAR1 VAR2 $255 ;
     set SNOWFLK.TABLE;
   run;

or if you know the individual lengths, and/or want to rename variables:
   data DL; 
     length VAR1 $&len1 VAR2 $&len2 ;
     set SNOWFLK.TABLE
       (rename=(LONGVARIABLENAME = VAR2))  
   quit;

If the names are longer than 32 in length, you should rename on the remote  (SnowFlake) side using SQL pass-through. The data length reduction can also happen there, which is even better as it lowers the amount of data transferred. Something like:
   libname SNOWFLK <connection parameters..>;
   proc sql;
     connect using SNOWFLK;
     create table DL as select * from connection to SNFLKLIB (  
       /* Write a valid snowflake query here, fix below to fit */
       select cast(VAR1 as varchar(&len1)) as VAR1
            , cast(OVERLYVERBOSEANDLONGVARIABLENAME123 as varchar(&len2)) as VAR2 
       from TABLE
       /* End of Snowflake query*/
     ); 
   quit;

